# What does $\ln{z} - \ln{z}$ equal, given $z \in \mathbb{C}$?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, paradoxes

On first glance, the expression
$$
\ln{z} - \ln{z}
$$
where $z$ is complex and of form $a + bi$ should always evaluate to zero. Subtracting something by itself should be zero. However, when one takes the multivaluedness of the complex logarithm into account, one might find that
$$
\frac{1}{2}\ln(a^2+b^2)+i(Arg(z) + 2\pi k_1)\\ - \frac{1}{2}\ln(a^2+b^2)-i(Arg(z) + 2\pi k_2) 
\\
=2 \pi i(k_1-k_2)
$$
where $k_1,k_2 \in \mathbb{Z}$. Let $c = k_1-k_2$ and we finally have the relation
$$
\ln{z} - \ln{z} = 2 \pi i c
$$
where $c \in \mathbb{Z}$.
This feels incredibly hacky and not at all rigorous. However, I can't quite see where my problem lies. Is multivaluedness not treated this way with rigor? Which step did I commit some "division by zero" type error? Or if this is true, is there an intuition for it?

Comment: What you are doing here is set subtraction. For example if $A = \{1,2\}$ and $B = \{1\}$, then $A-B = \{0,1\}$. If $B = \{5,6\}$, then $A-B = \{-4,-5,-3\}$. Moreover, $A-A = \{0,-1,1\}$.

Comment: The problem you have is in confusing numbers and sets; for numbers it is true that that $a-a=0$, for sets it is definitely not true that $A-A=$ {$0$} but only that $0$ strictly $\in A-A$ as long as $A$ has more than one element. $\ln z$ is apriori an infinite set for complex $z$ unless a given choice has  been made, so that is the reason that difference is infinite

Answer (score 0):

No, $\ln(z)-\ln(z)=0$ and $k_1=k_2$ in what you wrote. When you write $\ln(z)=\ln|z|+i\arg(z)$, then $\arg(z)\in (-\pi,\pi]$. If you don't do such a restriction, then $\arg(z)$ is not a function.

Comment: $\ln: \mathbb C\to \mathbb C$. Do I miss something ? @Jean-ClaudeArbaut